# MySQL, query two tables and check if photos are assigned to category

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, **photos** and **photos_categories**.

Table's **photos** rows are: id, **usr_id**, photo_name, **cat_id**, etc

Table's **photos_categories** rows are: **cat_id**, **usr_id**, cat_name, etc

I want to query these two tables and get the cat_name for a certain usr_id from **photos_categories** and also get the folowing info from **photos**:
1. if there are any rows with photos for each cat_id
or 
2. the number of photos that each cat_id has

The purpose of this query is to forbid deleting a category if there are photos assigned to it.

---

A more detailed example

[table's structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg8Dn.gif)

User with usr_id=10 has created three categories. The same user has assigned four photos in two of these categories and one category has left with no photo assigned to it. I want to query these two tables and get as a result the three categories with the number of photos assigned to each one, even if number of photos is null.

Comment: Nikos you need to show what you have tried.

Comment: And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this one:

```
SELECT
    category.cat_id,
    category.cat_name,
    COUNT(photos.*) AS numPhotos
FROM
    photos_categories AS category
LEFT JOIN
    photos ON
    photos.cat_id = category.cat_id
WHERE
    category.usr_id = ?
GROUP BY
    category.cat_id
HAVING
    numPhotos > 0
```

Skip the `HAVING` part if you generally want to count how many images there are in a category.